# When using fetch do I have to specify the url endpoint I want to get from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

Say it is a single page app and the user is at url: `test.com/cow`. While on this page when they use fetch do that have to do `fetch('/cow')` to let the server know that they are calling from the `/cow` url or if you call fetch like this `fetch('/')` will it know to route to `/cow` in express since when the user sent fetch it was from `/cow` url? I am confused.

Comment: That depends if the client and the server are on the same server, otherwise you will have to give absolute path of the API end point.

Comment: The client app is served from the same server that the future requests go to. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean the client and server are physically on the same machine so the only time I wouldn't have to use absolute paths is if I'm testing locally on my computer during development?

Comment: If the client (web browser) and server (node/express in your case) are on the same server, you simply supply the path ('/cow') to the fetch parameter. The node/express will not route your request based on the sending url (I'm sure you could program it to do that but you would limit each web page to one API end point if you did that).